# How do I get data for a spesific user without passing Id as paramater?

Tags: c#, api, uwp, authorization, ef-core-2.0

I am making an API with .NET Core 2.1 with SQL database and EF core.

My "Item" model contains a User because when an Item is created it belonges to a User.

How am I supposed to query Items for a User from det database in my API? I feel like its bad practice to pass the userID as a paramater in a GET request.

I think I need som kind of token authorization, but all I can find on the internet is about making access for roles. I need a user to only be able to access its own data.

I am pretty new to all of this, so I will appreciate an easy solution.

Here is my current code(Not good practice?):

```
[HttpGet("{id}/items")]
public IEnumerable<Item> GetUserItems([FromRoute] int id)
{
   var items = Context.Items.Where(i => i.User.UserId == id);

   return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the items of the logged user, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and in _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User you should find what you need.

Otherwise add a GUID "IdentityId" with an index to the user class and query using that:

```
context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdentityId == guid)?.Items;
```

Comment: So it is considered OK to generate a GUID when a user is created, and pass that when accessing that given users items? I am a student and working on a exam project, so i need to follow good standards.

Comment: Yes exposing the ID is """bad practice""". Here an example from Microsoft itself where "Buyer" has an "IdentityGuid " property, while the integer ID used for relations is hidden in the Entity base class. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/BuyerAggregate/Buyer.cs

Answer (score 1):

They are 2 different things.

Firstly, passing ID is considered bad for some people (not me). To fix this, you may want to add a GUID column to your user table, then use that GUID instead of ID.

Secondly, about allowing 1 user to access only his own data. This requires some work. But in general you need to have a look at authentication claim-based (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In that link, in the example, you can see they use "EmployeeNumber" claim, you can do same thing with your new GUID column.

Comment: Whether an ID is a number, a string or a GUID in a get request the issues are the same. I agree that it's generally fine. Don't ever pass a password in a get request, but a user ID is fine.

Comment: That's why I said "(not me)". But agree with you, user ID is fine.

Comment: My point is, using a GUID as an ID and passing that has no benefit, at all. Passing a key, or a UUID that maps directly to a key (one to one) has the exact same net effect. Thus I'd remove this `To fix this, you may want to add a GUID column to your user table, then use that GUID instead of ID.`

Comment: I agree with you. My point is somebody say that it's more secured.